# How to handle onBackPressed for Android App with Bottom Navigation

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, onbackpressed, fragment-backstack

I have a MainActivity with BottomNavigation and a frameLayout. The BottomNavigation can navigate to three different fragments. But when i press the back button, the checked Item on my bottom nav does not check the correct menu item. How do i solve this problem? It's been bugging me for days now

Answer (score 1):

Better try to use NavHostFragment the newest way of Navigation -https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation. 
and you will not face this issue.

Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50626510/10735178

Comment: Thanks. It actually seems like this is the perfect tool to solve my problem.