# How to handle the back stack of bottom navigation with navigation component

Tags: java, android, kotlin, fragment-backstack

I want to perform a navigation just like instagram and youtube and i tried many ways how should it be implemented? by the way it should work with the Jetpack's Navigation Component what is the newest and easiest and most reliable approach? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Look sample navigation at https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Jetpack Navigation, BottomNavigationView with Youtube or Instagram like proper back navigation (fragment back stack)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577356/android-jetpack-navigation-bottomnavigationview-with-youtube-or-instagram-like)