# Navigation Arch Component and Fragments Recreation

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I used `BottomNavigationView` along with `NavHostFragment` and I have only 2 tabs at the moment, down below the Navigation Graph I used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/main_navigation"
  app:startDestination="@id/fragment1">

  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="something.ListingFragment"
    android:label="@string/hello" />

  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:name="something.ListingFragment2"
    android:label="@string/Hi" />

</navigation>
```

---

And the BottomNavigation Menu is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <item
    android:id="@id/fragment1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic1"
    android:title="@string/hello"
    tools:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
  <item
    android:id="@id/fragment2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic2"
    android:title="@string/hi"
    tools:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

All setuped together using:

```
val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation_view)
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navHostFragment.navController)
```

---

Question is, every time I switch between tabs it creates a new instance of the tab fragment I click on, is there a way to manage this to prevent the creation of new items if it already exists in the memory?

Comment: you can check out this answer it fixed my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51684125

Comment: @mbayram93 thanks, ill give it a try