# BottomNavigationView with NavController reusable fragments with back stack

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I'm trying to implement this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51684125/3278271) using [Google Jetpack Navigation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation.html) component and still struggle with back stack issue.

The problem I'm facing is a custom implementation of navigating method in FragmentNavigator class breaks existing logic of back stack.

**if I try to add simple behavior like:**

```
transaction.addToBackStack(tag)
```

then BottomNavigationView is not highlighting/selecting buttons properly for a current active fragment when the back button is pressed.

My question how to implement properly custom back stack using such approach that works correctly with BottomNavigationView and properly using the back pressed listener to override more advanced custom back stack that put right navigation in the same BottomNavigationView?

The naive approach would be override onBackPressed in activity and then just create own logic separately and manually use `navController.navigate` to simulate back stack functionality, but I would like to hear how this problem can be solved with BottomNavigationView, NavController, NavHostFragment, FragmentNavigator scope.

Comment: ok, what do you want, by back press in bottonNavigation you want activity to go back or you want fragment on bottom navigation to go back satck?

Comment: these things happens when we do custom stuffs.

Comment: @HussnainHaidar let's say I just want functionality like YouTube app when it remember your unique visited fragment and then when you click back button it just pop previous fragment form back stack and correctly represent it in bottonNavigation until you reach home fragment if you press back button on home fragment application just exit.

Comment: does it work? and are you calling bottomNavigation fragment by menu item id?

Comment: @HussnainHaidar i replied to you in your answer.

Comment: ok, i check that project then reply to you.