# How to keep the last opened fragment with navigation component

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, navigationcontroller

I have a problem I am using the new navigation controller from Android Jetpack. I have 3 items in my bottom navigation menu, and the first item has 5 fragments one after another. When I click to the second item in bottom navigation, and return to my first item it opens the first fragment not the last opened. Because `android:id="@+id/destination_home"`  in Menu is the same as the same as id in my navigation graph.

Can anyone advice the best solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For now navigation component not supports of saving "multi stack". This issue can be fixed with custom navigation controller: https://github.com/STAR-ZERO/navigation-keep-fragment-sample
P.S.: also in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50485988/is-there-a-way-to-keep-fragment-alive-when-using-bottomnavigationview-with-new-n) guy has same problem and you can see the answer, maybe it will help you.

Comment: thanks! That really sucks, it was main reason why I wanted to use it