# Saving scroll of RecyclerView with navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm using the Navigation Component with a BottomNavigationView in my app. It switches between 4 destinations one of which contains a fragment with a RecyclerView containing hundreds of items. When I use the back button the RecyclerView restores with the previous scroll position. But When I use BottomNavigationView to switch between destinations, It won't restore to previous position and resets to the top of RecyclerView. Here's the code I tried to prevent that

```
    override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()

    lastScrollPos = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        card_recyclerView.layoutManager?.scrollToPosition(lastScrollPos)
}
```

This is not workign what is the best way of restoring RecyclerView to correct position?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it does not scroll to the previous position is the `navController` recreates the fragment (using replace) when used with the `bottomNavigation`.

A simple approach to save the scroll state is to store the `layoutManager` state in `onDestroyView` and restore it on `onCreateView` unlike the scrollToPosition this approach will scroll to **the exact position** when the NavController recreates the fragment.

I posted full code in another thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/66940957/2102794

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by saving the Y-Axis position of the `ScrollView` in a member variable and restore it in `onCreateView()`. This works because the member variables are not destroyed.

```
class DiscoverDataFragment : BaseFragment() {
    private var loaded = false
    private var scrollPos = 0
    
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_discover_data, container, false)
    }
    
    override fun onCreateBind() {
        super.onCreateBind()  
        if (!loaded) {
            // Load views here
            loaded = true
        }
        
        if (scrollPos > 0) {
            scrollDiscoverData.scrollY = scrollPos
        }
    
        setScrollListener()
    }
    
    private fun setScrollListener() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            scrollDiscoverData.setOnScrollChangeListener { v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY ->
            scrollPos = scrollY
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you must initialize adapter outside fragment lifecycle, for example

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

private val myViewModel by viewModel<MyViewModel>()
private lateinit var myAdapter : MyAdapter

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    myAdapter = MyAdapter()
    Log.d("checkListData", myAdapter.currentList.toString())
    myViewModel.someListData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ listData ->
        myAdapter.submitList(listData)
    }
}}
```

Comment: Oh, common man. Learn Android framework first. This is an anti-pattern as it is one big memory leak.