# Save state of fragment A when navigating from bottomNavigationView to fragment B

Tags: android, android-fragments, uinavigationbar, bottomnavigationview, onsaveinstancestate

I am new to Android and I have been struggling for some time now with saving state of a fragment.
My app has 5 options in the bottomNavigationView (I am using the default activity from Android). In fragment A (actually called "SearchFragment") I have a button and when clicked it sets some text in a TextBox. I want to save the state of this fragment (with the text there) when navigating to another fragment and the coming back to the fragment A (and have the text still there from the previous button click).

From the code I wrote **it saves the fragment's state when changing orientation for example, but doesn't do so when navigating to other fragments and then coming back.**

How could I change the code? Or is there any other method to save the current state of a fragment on navigation? I really need some help here...and thanks for your attention!

My mainActivity looks like this:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
            // menu should be considered as top level destinations.

            AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                    R.id.navigation_search, R.id.navigation_explore, R.id.navigation_trips, R.id.navigation_groups,R.id.navigation_profile)
                    .build();

            NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
            NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
            NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
        }

    }
```

**And the fragment class looks like this:**

```
    public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {

        private SearchViewModel searchViewModel;
        Button b;
        TextView text;
        Bundle savedState = null;

        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                                 ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

            searchViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SearchViewModel.class);
            final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_dashboard);
            searchViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                    textView.setText(s);
                }
            });
            Log.i("state","onCreate");
            Log.i("bundleIsNull", "" + (savedState == null));


            b  = root.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            text = root.findViewById(R.id.textView);


            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    text.setText("YEEEY");
                    Log.i("bundleIsNull", "" + (savedState == null));
                }
            });


            if(savedInstanceState != null && savedState == null) {
                savedState = savedInstanceState.getBundle("buttonText");
            }
            if(savedState != null) {
                text.setText(savedState.getCharSequence("buttonText"));
            }
            savedState = null;

            return root;
        }


        @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView();
            Log.i("state", "onDestroyView");
           savedState = saveState();
           text = null;
           b = null;
        }

        private Bundle saveState() {
            Bundle state = new Bundle();
            state.putCharSequence("buttonText", text.getText());
            return state;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            Log.i("state", "onSaveInstanceState");
            outState.putBundle("buttonText", (savedState != null)? savedState : saveState());
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            Log.i("state","onPause");
        }
    }
```

Comment: see this solution that create custom navigator. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51684125/10300202

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Few facts around Android Navigation Component with Bottom Navigation Bar.

**- > Fragments are always recreated (onCreate, onViewCreated, onViewDestroyed are called as soon as the user navigates to another fragment)**

**- > Fragment will save its state only when activity is recreated (e.g. screen rotation) , navigating between fragments doesn't save fragment's state.**

> I want to save the state of this fragment (with the text there) when
>   navigating to another fragment and the coming back to the fragment A
>   (and have the text still there from the previous button click).

This wont be possible as a new instance of FragmentA is created when
you navigate back from fragmentB to Fragment A.

you can not achieve this with navigation controller as of now.

Since you are using **navigation component**, You should switch to using **Viewmodel** to solve retain fragment state issue.

Consult the following link to see how to communicate and save data between fragments using viewmodel.

https://androidwave.com/fragment-communication-using-viewmodel/

Comment: Thank you for your help !! It worked :) I added a **sharedViewModel** for all the fragments and now it works

Comment: Hey @Kate could you share how you did it on github or something? Thank you!

Comment: with a videmodel being used for this purpose, is there a way that we can do `scrollToPosition` with `recycler view` . Since the view model keeps the latest pulled data and that is restored. We can always append data to adapter and while changing fragment update list in `viewmodel` and on restore, publish back in the adapter, but this always scrolls to top but not the last saved ui position and `scrollToPosition` would not work too. Any ideas ?

Comment: @Kate sharedViewModel save a Fragment, but doesn't save its View

Comment: How to save fragment view? For example i have google / yandex map and if i use a navigation component this map fragments are recreated always