# Android BottomNavigationView with Navigation Component issue

Tags: android, navigation, bottomnavigationview

I'm implementing `BottomNavigationView` integrated with `Navigation Component`, everything works perfectly, but I'm wondering how to make `Fragments` not being recreated while swiping between `BottomNavigationView`  icons.

It was possible with the usage of `ViewPager` by calling `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(n)` where `n` is the number of fragments.

Is there any alternatives for `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(n)` while using `BottomNavigationView` with `Navigation Component`

Comment: I would suggest you use `ViewPager2`.

Comment: I'm already using `Navigation Component` and i want to solve this problem with it

Comment: Umm? I'm not telling you to scrap `Navigation Component` I'm just saying you could use `ViewPager2` instead of `ViewPager`.

Comment: I'm not using `ViewPager` already, I'm asking for a method working like `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(n)` but in `Navigation Component`

Comment: I just found the best solution in the following question: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51684125/6700881](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51684125/6700881)