# multi navGraph BottomNavigationView in navigation 2.4.0

Tags: android, android-navigation-graph

I have 3 tabs A, B, C in `BottomNavigationView` and each has a nav graph.

I can do what I want perfectly in navigation 2.3.3 by a complicated navigation extension, just like the old [architecture-components-samples](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/). This sample is now upgrade to 2.4.0. which use less code.

What I want is:

Step: Graph A' s start destination fragment A1 navigate to A2.

Step: Tap tab B or C.

1. B or C' s `navigateUp` action is back to A. (works fine)
2. When back to tab A, it shows A2. (in 2.4.0' s sample, shows A1)
3. The BottomNavigationView' s ItemReselected action is `popBackStack` to current graph' s `startDestination`. (how to set `setOnItemReselectedListener` if the `navController` does not change?)
4. The three `startDestination` fragment A1, B1, C1 are top level destinations, so B1 and C1' s toolbar do not show back icon. (works fine, because the sample set a set of these 3 fragments instead of `navController.graph` to `AppBarConfiguration`)

[2.4.0 said it support Multiple back stacks.](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.4.0-alpha01) What does it mean? Can I make my BottomNavigationView in 2.4.0?

Here is how I do "3. The BottomNavigationView' s ItemReselected action..." in 2.3.3:

```
private fun BottomNavigationView.setupItemReselected(
    graphIdToTagMap: SparseArray<String>,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager
) {
    setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener { item ->
        ... // get the item' s navController
        navController.popBackStack(
            navController.graph.startDestination, false
        )
    }
}
```

What I do in 2.4.0:
just copy the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Add `setOnItemReselectedListener` and `popBackStack`

```kotlin
import android.util.SparseIntArray
import androidx.core.util.getOrElse

  private val startDestinationIdByNavId: SparseIntArray by lazy(NONE) {
    SparseIntArray(5).apply {
      put(R.id.tab_home_nav, R.id.tabHomeFragment)
      put(R.id.tab_profile_nav, R.id.tabMyProfileFragment)
    }
  }

  fun setupViews() {
    binding.bottomNavView.run {
      setupWithNavController(navController)

      // Pop the back stack to the start destination of the current navController graph
      setOnItemReselectedListener {
        navController.popBackStack(
          destinationId = startDestinationIdByNavId.getOrElse(it.itemId) {
            error("Unknown menu item $it")
          },
          inclusive = false,
        )
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this fix the bug of nested graphs on bottom navigation after version 2.3.5 of navigation!