# NullPointerException when i try to run fragment method from main activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to using fragments, I am trying to execute a fragment method from my main activity, the method compares a textview and then deletes cookies and loads a website.

This is what I have:

In MainActivity:

```
NavigatorFragment navigator = new NavigatorFragment();
navigator.refresh();
```

In Fragment:

```
public void refresh(){
    if (!textView.getText().toString().equals("Click HERE")){
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
        cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
        myWebView.loadUrl(URL);
    }
}
```

the result:
*java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference*

**EDIT**

Sorry but forget to mention that although the fragment is started the same thing happens, I previously used this code to prevent my fragments from restarting: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42362917/fragment-re-created-on-bottom-navigation-view-item-selected/59423979#59423979) So when I press item4 of my BottomNavigationView it opens the fragment, in onCreateView:

```
textView = root.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

when I press it again  (without having changed fragment) is when I want the method to be executed

I repeat, when I press item 4 BottomNavigationView for the first time, it opens Fragment 4 and loads its elements, when I press item 4 a second time (without having changed the fragment) that's when I want the method to run

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/*
Fragment MyFragment;
private NavController navController;
 */
NavigatorFragment navigator = new NavigatorFragment();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    replace_fragment(new HomeFragment());
}

private void replace_fragment(Fragment fragment) {

    String tag = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
    FragmentTransaction tr = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    Fragment curFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().getPrimaryNavigationFragment();
    Fragment cacheFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);

    if (curFrag != null)
        tr.hide(curFrag);

    if (cacheFrag == null) {
        tr.add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment, tag);
    } else {
        tr.show(cacheFrag);
        fragment = cacheFrag;
    }

    tr.setPrimaryNavigationFragment(fragment);
    tr.commit();

}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                replace_fragment(new HomeFragment());
                if (!getSupportActionBar().isShowing()){
                    showBar();
                }
                return true;

            case R.id.navigation_schedule:
                replace_fragment(new ScheduleFragment());
                if (!getSupportActionBar().isShowing()){
                    showBar();
                }
                return true;

            case R.id.navigation_calculators:
                replace_fragment(new CalculatorsFragment());
                if (!getSupportActionBar().isShowing()){
                    showBar();
                }
                return true;

            case R.id.navigation_navigator:
                replace_fragment(new NavigatorFragment());
                if (!getSupportActionBar().isShowing()){
                    navigator.refresh();//**************PROBLEM HERE******************************************
                }
                hideBar();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};



public void hideBar(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        // Call some material design APIs here
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();
    }
    else {
        // Implement this feature without material design
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
}

public void showBar(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        // Call some material design APIs here
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).show();
    }
    else {
        // Implement this feature without material design
        getSupportActionBar().show();
    }
}
```

}

**the refresh method works if run from the fragment code

Comment: Can you show how `textView` is (supposed to be) initialized?  There's not enough here to debug currently.

Comment: Done, I updated the question I hope you can help me, thanks @RyanM

Comment: I generally agree with Zain's answer.  You may also have the problem that you're not setting `navigator` in `replace_fragment`, so you're using a Fragment that has not been started instead of one that has.

Comment: I thank you very much, I will continue testing, I hope to solve it

Answer (score 1):

When instantiating a fragment instance using `new NavigatorFragment()` that doesn't involve that the [fragment life cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Creating) starts away. Meaning that the fragment isn't created, started, resumed, and shown on the screen.. So, accessing fragment's views at this moment will return `NullPointerException`.

So, what you need to do is to have a placeholder for the fragment in the activity layout, and start fragment transaction by [adding](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#add(int,%20androidx.fragment.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)) or [replacing](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#replace(int,%20androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)) fragments in this placeholder, which makes the fragment passes by its all life cycle callback methods, and to give it a chance to create its view (layout) on the screen within the [`onCreateView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) lifecycle callback, where you can just allowed to access the underlying `TextView` or any other view in this fragment, and use their methods like in your case `textView.getText()` subsequently without `NullPointerException`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033602/how-to-use-fragments-in-android) you can find how to use a fragment the right way.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I think it is not that, sorry but forget to mention that although the fragment is started the same thing happens, I previously used this code to prevent my fragments from restarting: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59423979/13452141) So when I press item4 of my BottomNavigationView it opens the fragment, when I press it again a second time (without having changed fragment) is when I want the method to be executed